# Segmentation fault (core dumped) and how to setup new python environments

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu, pytorch, ubuntu-17.10

How to manage the new environment when I run many projects? For instance, I was usually got the errors during training where I updated the libraries such as matplotlib and skimage and my system oupute the error like : Segmentation fault (core dumped).

It's probably to handle new environments to new project that will not conflict with my current projects. Any tutorial or ideas about this. I currently working on Ubuntu 17.10, Python 3.6, Tensorflow, and Pytorch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Anaconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/getting-started.html#) for [managing packages & versions](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-packages)?